# !newData.exists() always denies data push to database

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Im Making a posts system for my app and !newData.exists() or !data.exists() is always giving me permission denied, I also tried it without an exclamation mark but when I did then the database was always passing my data,

I was pushing data with a simple command which is

```
firebase.database().ref("posts").push().set({
   content: "Test",
   creator: "4p3dAIZKl9WSXpXyGlXOhyn5s692",
   image: "false",
   imageURL: "",
   timestamp: Date.now()
})
```

and while my rules for posts were

```
"posts":{
   ".read": "auth !== null",
   ".write": "!newData.exists()"
}
```

but when I did firebase was always giving me an error which was "PERMISSION_DENIED"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `newData` variable refers to the data at the path where it is declared after the write operation (assuming that it succeeds). Since you're writing data under `posts`, `newData.exists()` is by definition true once that operation is allowed.

If you're trying to ensure that a user can only write a post if one doesn't exist in that path yet, you need the exact opposite (and one level lower in the rules):

```
"posts":{
  "$postid": {
    ".read": "auth !== null",
    ".write": "!data.exists()"
  }
}
```

So now you can only write a specific new post, if there is no data for that path in the database yet.